# Create an excel file from DTS ActiveX Task

Tags: sql, dts

I need create ten different excel files from DTS ActiveX Task. Just create, not manipulated it. I just know that I have to use

> CreateObject(Excel.Application)

and

> CreateObject(Scripting.FileSystemObject)

Thanks for a while.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL 2005+, see following URL
http://oakdome.com/programming/SSIS_ActiveXScript_to_ScriptTask.php

UPD. Added vbscript for file creation. Just use it in your DTS Script task

```
fileName = "d:\test_file.xls"

Set excelObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
excelObj.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = excelObj.Workbooks.Add()
objWorkbook.SaveAs(fileName)

excelObj.Quit
```